# javascript - Server not handle event (socket.io/node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I've just started with Node.js/ Socket.io and want to build an sample app in which:

- When connected, both server and client print 'connected!'.
- Everytime client submit a message, server print content and respond back to client.

Here is my code:

NodeJS 0.6.7

Socket.IO 0.8.7

Server script:

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(8081);
io.set("log level", 1);
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  console.log('connected!');
  socket.on('sendchat', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    socket.emit('updatechat', data);
  });
});
```

Client script:

```
<script src="http://localhost:8081/socket.io/socket.io.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<div id="main-content">
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
            var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8081');

            socket.on('connect', function () {
                document.getElementById('main-content').innerHTML = '<p>connected!</p>';
            });

            socket.on('updatechat', function (data) {
                document.getElementById('main-content').innerHTML += '<p>'+data+'</p>';
            });

            function sendMessageToServer() {
                var message = document.chatfrm.content.value;
                socket.emit('sendchat', message);
                document.chatfrm.content.value = '';
            }
        </script>
        <div id="chat">
            <form action="" id="chat-frm" name="chatfrm">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td><textarea id="content" cols="30" rows="5" name="content"></textarea></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <input type="button" value="Post" id="submit" onclick="sendMessageToServer()"/>
            </form>
        </div>
```

However, only server print 'connected!' when server & client are connected. Besides, when client submit message, server doesn't log content as I expected.

Thank for your help!

Comment: Does the console have any errors?

Comment: @DeaDEnD No. But when I comment out the line " io.set("log level", 1); " I got some logs on console:    debug - setting request GET /socket.io/1/xhr-polling/5396302231205660241?t=13
27141016494
   debug - setting poll timeout
   debug - discarding transport
   debug - cleared heartbeat interval for client 5396302231205660241

Comment: @DeaDEnD I just realize that my code work fine with IE8, but not work on Chrome 17 or FF 9 (the 'connect' event of client is never fired). I don't know if there're something caused by WebSockets protocol or not. Hope you could help. Thanks very much.

Comment: There might be a mistake with your client side code. Use `console.log` to debug instead of the DOM.